# Responsive, scrolling images

Tags: html, css, image

I'm SURE there is a stupid easy answer to this, but I'm just learning to code and I can't figure out what is going on here.

http://bit.ly/1zuki3W

The images adjust to the screen size, but the page doesn't let you scroll. But the background does move.

So, how do I freeze my background image (that may just be a bounce back in Apples OS?)?

And, how do I get the ability to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the position fixed attribute from the body css like

```
body {
background: url(pictures/Backgroundtest.jpg);
/* position: fixed;  remove this attribute */
font: Palatino;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
overflow: auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should only remove the position:fixed from the body

Thanks!